# How to get the tikz/font pgfkey value and pass is to \pgfnode command

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-core, pgfkeys

Let's say that I'm writing a decoration where I use the `\pgfnode` command in it. It works well but if I change the `pgfkey` TikZ/font to any dimension, it is not passed to the nodes in the decoration. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 5):

Searching on `tikz.code.tex` I found the following line:

```
\tikzoption{font}{\def\tikz@textfont{#1}}
```

so the `tikz/font` value is stored into `\tikz@textfont`. To use it into my node in decoration, I write:

```
{
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{<x value>}{<y value>}}
\tikz@textfont
\pgfnode{rectangle}{south}{<text>}{<node name>}{\pgfusepath{<use path option>}}
}
```

That's all